# Losing audioCapture in a Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, getusermedia, audio-capture

In my manifest i added the audioCapture permission.

```
"permissions": ["audioCapture"]
```

I tryed differents scenario to see if my app is alway working. I close the app, close Chrome, reopen my app and sometime i'm loosing the audio captur. Audio capture is in runing in the backgound.js

The only way i can restart my audio is remove the audioCapture permission from my manifest, reopen my app. i got a error for getusermedia and it's okay. Put back the audio capture in the permission. Reload the app. and now my audio capture is back.

How can i be sure in that in every conditions, app open, closed, Chrome closed ect.. that my app will alway be ready to capture audio when i trigger a action.

Answer (score 0):

You may include '*background*' in your permissions. '*background*' makes Chrome start up early and shut down late, so that apps and extensions can have a longer life.

Chrome runs as soon as the user logs into their computer. The '*background*' permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits chrome.

Note: Disabled apps and extensions are treated as if they aren't installed.

For more information, follow this link: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions